# Pass current selected row of p:dataTable to JavaScript function in p:ajax oncomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

How can I pass current selected row to JavaScript function in `<p:ajax oncomplete>`?

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bolt.sites}" var="bolt" selection="#{bolt.selectedSite}" ...>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="alert(#{bolt.selectedSite.name});" />
```

I have tried all: `#{bolt.selectedSite.name}`, `#{bolt.name}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EL expressions in `oncomplete` attribute are not evaluated after invoking the action. They are already evaluated while rendering the JavaScript code containing that ajax calling logic.

Your best bet is adding a listener method which adds the name as a callback parameter via [`RequestContext#addCallbackParam()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#addCallbackParam(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) which will then be available as a property of the implicit `args` object inside `oncomplete` context.

```
<p:ajax ... listener="#{bean.select}" oncomplete="alert(args.name)" />
```

```
public void select() {
    String name = selectedSite.getName();
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("name", name);
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you have a syntax error in your initial JavaScript attempt. The property name "name" suggests that it's a string. In JavaScript, all string values should be quoted. So your fictive solution would be `oncomplete="alert('#{bolt.selectedSite.name}');"`